# Adobe Photoshop & Illustrator file preview in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I'm a designer who deals with a lot of psd and ai files and it's very time consuming to sort through multiple files.

I was wondering if it were possible to use Windows Explorer's file preview feature to view my files before opening them.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't Photoshop have a built-in file browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

**First,** use a free tool like [Thumbview](http://www.seriema.net/thumbview/) or [psicon.dll](https://www.google.com/search?q=psicon.dll).

**Second,** purchase a codec that allows you to preview .PSD files in Explorer. Most codecs / packages will allow you to preview many other files that might also be of use to use. Some good ones include [PSD-codec by Ardfry](http://www.ardfry.com/psd-codec/) or [Fast Picture Viewer](http://www.fastpictureviewer.com/codecs/) (which supports the viewing of other files as icons such as InDesign and illustrator).

Comment: Thanks, I can't stand Adobe Bridge. This is going to be great, i like the links.